# Prevent backslash escaping in CSV import

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel for importing products from CSV files.

CSV settings:

- ISO-8859-1 format
- Comma as delimiter.
- " as enclosure

A few of the products have a name ending with a backslash. 
Ex.: Example product model DN123\

Looking at the raw CSV file in a text editor, it will look like this:
... "Example product model DN123\", "Shoes", "Men" ...

When importing it's perceived as the enclousure (") after the backslash is escaped. How can I prevent this? When I open the CSV in the mac-program Numbers everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not well documented, but the escape_character can be changed in custom CSV settings. I changed it to " and it worked.